# Attach debugger to specific WCF endpoint on server

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging

I am trying to use the remote debugger to connect VS 2013 to my server that is currently hosting my WCF web service. Normally this works great, but right now I am trying to debug some test code that exists in a separate application on my server. So the endpoints look like this:

```
 - http://myserver.com/testing/myservice.svc
 - http://myserver.com/production/myservice.svc
```

If public my test code to the `testing` endpoint and try to attach the debugger, my breakpoints never work and say their symbols have not been loaded. However, if I publish to **both** endpoints using my code, I am then able to use breakpoints with the remote debugger.

Is there any way I can tell the `Attach to Process` or the remote debugger to only remote debug a specific endpoint/application that is hosted on my server? I don't want the remote debugger and VS to try to hook into the entire `w3wp.exe` if that's going to make it attempt to debug `every` application that is hosted on that server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're okay attaching to w3wp.exe (in fact, you need to).

w3wp.exe is an IIS worker thread process which means there should be a separate instance per application.

The likely reason publishing to both endpoints "works" is that you're probably attaching your debugger to the w3wp.exe process associated with your production instance, which means that until the code at your production endpoint is updated to match your debugging symbols, trying to debug production with newly-modified symbols won't work.